# How to get the difference of two ISO String dates with an aggregation MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, datetime, aggregation-framework, isodate

I have a collection called biosignals in my MongoDB, in which there exist entries that represent physical activity (e.g. walking).

Each such entry has a 'start_date_time' and an 'end_date_time', which are ISO strings (e.g. 2017-04-26T07:12:09.463Z).

I want to do the following query, where I group the physical activity entries by day and I calculate the total duration of activity for each day.

```
db.biosignals.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "name": "physical-activity"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            duration: {
                "$subtract": [new Date("$end_date_time"), new Date("$start_date_time")]
            },
            date: {
                $substr: [ "$start_date_time", 0, 10]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$date",
            total: { $sum: "$duration" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            _id: 1
        }
    }
])
```

However, I only get 0 as a result, as shown here:

```
{ "_id" : "2017-04-24", "total" : NumberLong(0) }
{ "_id" : "2017-04-25", "total" : NumberLong(0) }
{ "_id" : "2017-04-26", "total" : NumberLong(0) }
{ "_id" : "2017-04-27", "total" : NumberLong(0) }
```

If, instead, I hardcode the dates (e.g. start_date_time = 2017-04-26T07:12:08.463Z and end_date_time = 2017-04-26T07:12:09.463Z, that is one second difference), I get the expected result:

```
{ "_id" : "2017-04-24", "total" : NumberLong(16000) }
{ "_id" : "2017-04-25", "total" : NumberLong(3000) }
{ "_id" : "2017-04-26", "total" : NumberLong(7000) }
{ "_id" : "2017-04-27", "total" : NumberLong(12000) }
```

How could I fix that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is not possible to cast a date from a string in the aggregation framework. Your `Date("$end_date_time")` statements are in fact **not** being executed in the aggregation pipeline at all but are actually being "evaluated" **before** the pipeline is sent to the server. And if you pick up that statement and drop it into your favorite JavaScript interpreter it is going to return the current date and time. This is being evaluated into the pipeline as a constant of "current date" - "current date" which of course is equal to `0`. Try it in an interpreter yourself and see what I say is true.

Comment: Bottom line is if you want to perform "Date Math" operations in the aggregation framework, then you need to convert your "string" to an actual `Date` by updating the data. Otherwise use map reduce which can cast to a `Date` on the fly.